# CountIFs in Excel with VBA is not counting decimal values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the function CountIF when used with decimals.

Below the code I have:

```
Sub Compair()
    
    Dim I As Double
    
    Row = 3
   
    For I = 139.5 To 141.5 Step 0.25
        
        Cells(Row, 3) = I
        Cells(Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "<" & Cells(Row, 3))
                
        Row = Row + 1
        
    Next I

End Sub
```

And below the output:

[image: Compair Subroutine result]

It seems that the code functions good when it is compairing integer value and not with decimals.
PS: I do not want to loop on column A cells, as there could be more than 100k values and it will be so slowly

Comment: I suspect it's the comma in your value. Try replacing it with a full stop in your criteria string.

Comment: ^^ `Cells(Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "<" & Replace(I, ",", ".")`

Comment: @JvdV `I` will have the `.` as it is the variable for the loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner, funny enough it won't. I tried the code and because I'm in Dutch locale I could reproduce the faulty results. The above line [worked for me producing the correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZblF.gif)

Comment: @JvdV can you try my answer to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct

just confirm your region, if you need the comas as decimal separatos configure your Windows format, and your excel format

Windows Format
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10
Excel Format
https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/formatting-cells/1/

[image]

```
Sub Compair()       
    Range("A16").Select
    Dim I As Double    
    Row = 16   
    For I = 139.5 To 141.5 Step 0.25        
        Cells(Row, 3) = I
        Cells(Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "<" & Cells(Row, 3))                
        Row = Row + 1        
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull everything into variant arrays, which will be quicker on larger datasets than COUNTIFS:

```
Sub Compair()

    With ActiveSheet
         Dim rngArr As Variant
         rngArr = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))).Value2
         
         
         Dim outArr() As Variant
         ReDim outArr(1 To Int((141.5 - 139.5) / 0.25) + 1, 1 To 2)
         
         
         Dim I As Double
         
         Row = 1
        
         For I = 139.5 To 141.5 Step 0.25
             
             outArr(Row, 1) = I
             outArr(Row, 2) = 0

             Dim j As Long
             For j = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 1)
                If rngArr(j, 1) < I Then outArr(Row, 2) = outArr(Row, 2) + 1
             Next j
                     
             Row = Row + 1
             
         Next I
         .Range("C3").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), 2).Value = outArr
    End With
    
    

End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV added the default `0` so it is not blank if there are none that are less than the number.